Could Dukkha be interpeted as anxiety?
I have an anxiety disorder and I sometimes wonder if Dukkha could be viewed as anxiety. In other words in the four noble truths:
This is anxiety.
This is the cause of anxiety.
This is the cessation of anxiety.
This is the path of practice of anxiety.
Isn't Dukkha really just a form of anxiety? Anxiety about emotional pain and even the suffering associated with physical pain is probably anxiety, horror at the pain and the risk of death.
I don't know. I think this could be a translation of Dukkha. But maybe I should just use it myself because I have an anxiety disorder...

The term 'dukkha' is best translated as 'discontentment': a state where the perceived conditions of the world do not match internal expectations of the world. Say we buy a new car and then realize it's not quite as shiny, powerful, or 'cool' as we imagined it to be: that mental disconnect is dukkha. Dukkha is like a mental hook that can snag any number of emotions or attitudes: anger, sorrow, righteousness, disappointment, irritation, depression, or (yes) anxiety… It's important to make this distinction between the simple discontentment with a condition, and the array of mental states that get snagged and dragged along.
We can think of anxiety as a free-floating anticipation of dukkha, a nebulous belief that events in the world are not ever likely to go the way we imagine they should, so that we always have to be on guard for the inevitable obstacles, but again, we need to distinguish between the belief that the world is constantly at odds with us and the emotion that has affixed itself to that belief. This is, I think, really what the first three points of the Four Noble Truths are saying:

Discontentment (dukkha) occurs
Attitudes like craving and aversion (fear, anxiety, desire, anguish, greed… tanhā) arise and fuse with dukkha, leading to their endless recreation
(Seeing this distinction) the attitudes of tanhā can be decoupled, and (once decoupled from the observation of dukkha) they well fade away and cease to be.

My 2¢…

translating attitude as 'craving and aversion' is a little confusing, but it makes sense when considering attitude to mean sankappa

@blue_eggo: Hah! I have't run across the term sankappa before; neat. I like the term attitude here because I think of this holistically. So like, if we're at a baseball game and the pitcher winds up for a pitch, every player on the field shifts their physical posture, focal attention, and thought patterns — their physical/mental attitude — to prepare for the hit.

@blue_eggo: Or if you go to a hook-up bar you can watch people as they scan the room. When they see someone they desire, their eyes snap into focus, their chest puffs up, you can see them mentally check their hair and their breath, adjust their clothes, start thinking about the right approach. That whole change is a shift into an attitude of craving. Very interesting to watch…

Anything that makes you sad is Dukkha, whether it is pain , sorrow, lamentation , anxiety, disappointment etc. Dukkha covers every kind of suffering big or small. Sometimes Dukkha is very subtle , sometimes dukkha shows on your face. When Buddha said Dukkha , he covered every kind of suffering. Nibbana is the only solution to get rid of Dukkha forever.

Yeah, anything you don't like, even a little, is suffering. But the things you do like also cause suffering when they change or you lose them, because of craving and clinging. Actually the Teachings say everything is dukkha, unsatisfactory, stress. Anxiety is one of the most unsatisfactory things there is. But fear is a specific kind of stress, and dukkha encompasses all kinds, even those that don't seem unsatisfactory at the time.

For only stress is what comes to be;
stress, what remains & falls away.
Nothing but stress comes to be.
Nothing ceases but stress. -SN 5.10
 
Change occurs in this man's body, and it becomes different. On account of this change and difference, sorrow, lamentation, pain, grief and despair arise. [Similarly with feelings, perceptions, mental formations, consciousness]. -SN 22.43
 
"And is it proper to regard what is inconstant, stressful, subject to change as: 'This is mine. This is my self. This is what I am'?"
"No, my friend." -SN 22.85

Ajahn Brahm said as long as you want things to be different than they are, you'll never be happy.

Anxiety is udhacca-kukkucca, an elevated type of dukkha typical of those with relatively higher self-awareness.
It's good in a sense that you're not blind to your potential mistakes and shortcomings, you worry about them and try to prevent missteps.
It's bad in a sense that when you have anxiety you're not stable. You second guess your every choice, spending a lot of energy and projecting a weak character outwardly. You cannot be a buoy to others until you are absolutely stable yourself, people need something to hold on to.
The Buddhist solution to this is to focus on finding the ground truth (nirvana, enlightenment, whatever you call it) in your own first-hand experience. Once you have found the truth, it is the unshakable foundation beyond any doubt, a firm ground you can really stand on. At that point you can be very confident, there's no more reason for anxiety.
How to get there? There are no shortcuts, only study of dharma, meditation, and applying the teaching in real life.
Coming back to your question, Dukkha in the Noble Truths is a much wider concept than just anxiety (you knew this!). Every time your subjective experience is not 100% in peace with "what is" - that is what we call dukkha. This can be an objective trouble you got yourself into by making an actual mistake, or it can be a wrong expectation. These are two major types of dukkha.
Most of the Buddhist path is focused on removing the causes of these two types of dukkha while udhacca-kukkucca is kinda accepted as an inevitable side effect of trying to be careful. It is something we have to live with until very last stages of the work.

The 1st noble truth refers to different types of suffering, which includes the suffering of not to get what one wants.
The 1st noble truth summarises all suffering as the five aggregates subject to clinging.
Anxiety is obviously a type of clinging; where the mind worries, ruminates & vacillates over a certain object or subject matter.
The Pali suttas in a number of places (MN 37,  MN 140, SN 12.51) literally say when clinging ends, anxiety & suffering end. Therefore, anxiety is certainly a type of suffering. These Pali suttas say:

Anupādiyaṁ na paritassati, aparitassaṁ paccattaññeva parinibbāyati
Not grasping (clinging), they’re not anxious. Not being anxious, they personally become extinguished (peaceful; cooled; calm; serene).
MN 37

The 2nd noble truth refers to three types of craving which can cause suffering when they manifest as a 'new becoming' ('ponobbhavikā'), namely:

Craving for sensual pleasures (kāmataṇhā).

Craving to be (bhavataṇhā).

Craving not to be (vibhavataṇhā).


The mental activity of 'becoming' ('bhava') is simply strong & prolonged clinging. The Pali suttas (AN 3.76) define 'bhava' as the mind 'established/fixated (patiṭṭhita)' upon a certain sense object due to craving & ignorance. Again, the Pali suttas say when this 'established/fixated (patiṭṭhita)' mind ends, anxiety ends, as follows:

Tadappatiṭṭhitaṁ viññāṇaṁ avirūḷhaṁ anabhisaṅkhacca vimuttaṁ.
Since that consciousness does not become established and does not
grow, with no power to regenerate, it is freed.
Vimuttattā ṭhitaṁ. Ṭhitattā santusitaṁ. Santusitattā na paritassati.
Aparitassaṁ paccattaññeva parinibbāyati.
Being free, it’s stable. Being stable, it’s content. Being content,
they’re not anxious. Not being anxious, they personally become
extinguished.
SN 22.53

In short, it appears anxiety can arise from any of the three types of craving; and can manifest as the suffering of not to get what one wants.
For example, there may be a sensual craving to connect with a certain person in a romantic way, which is craving for sensual pleasure. Due to this craving, the mind may worry one is not attractive enough or one has adverse qualities.
Or, for example, there may be the craving to be a certain profession (which is craving to be) however the mind worries one is not qualified or suitable enough.
Or, for example, the mind may have certain habits and there is the craving not to express those habits (which is craving not to be); and thus the worry or anxiety arises one may lack the self-control to prevent those habits.
In summary, it appears the suffering of anxiety will generally arise in relation to some desired context; which is thus caused by craving. In short, the mind wants something and worries it may not attain what it wants.
To conclude, yes, dukkha can certainly be interpreted as anxiety.

Presented as anxiety, you're making sound Dukkha as a clinical condition.
However, I think Dukkha means 'difficulty'. Anything turning to be troublesome and a burden is difficulty or 'dukkha'. Of course an anxiety disorder is indeed troublesome and hard to bear, it is dukkha, like many other things in life, big or small, that are hard to bear with or 'adversity'.
But Dukkha is broader than unpleasant anxiety feelings and all the implications of having an anxiety disorder. You can find it subtly in pleasant feelings as well. Or in how fine you happen to look. Or in whatever you recognize in your self. It's not confined to just anxiety, I'm afraid.

Taṇhā literally means drought or thirst.
Figuratively it means craving for..., hunger for..., excitement & fever with unsatisfied longing for...
They are seen mostly in...

kāma-taṇhā (craving for sensual pleasures)
bhava-taṇhā (craving for existence)
and vibhava-taṇhā (craving for non-existence)

These are what lead one round and round to birth after birth. This is a core problem in Buddhism.
Anxiety probably goes under worry and restlessness in the 5 hindrances (nivarana) (see similes here).

The noble truth of suffering (dukkha) is this: birth is suffering;
aging is suffering; sickness is suffering; death is suffering; sorrow
and lamentation, pain, grief, and despair are suffering; association
with the unpleasant is suffering; disassociation from the pleasant is
suffering; not to get what one wants is suffering. In brief, the five
aggregates of attachment are suffering.

Anxiety is probably also inferred in the above section of the Dhammacakka sutta also.
Thus the path of practice (the 8 fold path) is that which leads us to the end of suffering, so that would include overcoming of anxiety and taṇhā as that is a form of suffering.
Interestingly the positive form of desire is known as chanda in pali when used in such a wholesome way speaks about the good wholesome desire that is needed to attain spiritual practice, as seen 4 roads to power used in the cultivation of samadhi ... chanda (desire), virya (energy), cita (purity of mind), vimansa (skillful means). (in MN 16, they are listed in the last factors with ehosi (striving) as the 5th.
To overcome anxiety, one develops serenity. So anxiety seems to be more a result that can be overcome. Taṇhā is about the attachment that leads us to birth and suffering mostly.
